# Proving this inequality

Tags: inequality, problem-solving

I am having trouble with proving an inequality.
Assume we have two positive real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a+b=1$ and numbers $x > 0$ and $y > 0$. Prove:

$$\frac{2}{\frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{y}} \leq ax+by$$

I'd appreciate any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change 2 by 1 then the inequality holds

$1 \leq a^2+b^2 + ab(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}) $

$1 \leq (a+b)^2 + ab(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x})-2ab$

$1 \leq 1^2 + ab(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}-2)$

$0 \leq ab(\frac{x^2 + y^2 - 2xy}{xy}) $

$0 \leq ab(\frac{(x-y)(x-y)}{xy})$

$0 \leq ab(\frac{(x-y)^2}{xy})$

as $ab \geq 0$ , $(x-y)^2 \geq 0 $  and $xy > 0 $

Answer (score 1):

the function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$ is convex then :
$$a f(x) + b f(y) \geq f(a x + b y)$$
We deduce that :
$$\dfrac{a}{x} + \dfrac{b}{y} \geq \dfrac{1}{a x + b y}$$
hence :
$$\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{a}{x} + \dfrac{b}{y}} \leq a x + b y$$

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply out, you get $2 \le a^2+b^2+ab(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x})$. Do you know of an inequality to get a lower bound for the right-hand expression? By the way, sometimes it is useful to homogenize the equation by using the constraint, in this case we would multiply $(a+b)^2$ to the left-hand expression.

Comment: Ummm I know if a and b are both 1 then we have the inequality $2 \leq 1 + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x})$

Comment: Yea and since the equality case is $x=y$, you get that the inequality must have $1$ instead of $2$, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

The assertion is not true, consider the following counter example:$x=y=1 \implies 2\le 1$,perhaps "$2$" should be "$1$"

Comment: Are you saying the question itself is improper?

Comment: yes, if it is not typo.

Comment: I suggest you post this as a comment - this is not really appropriate as an answer.

Comment: It would make the question a lot easier if that is the case. Thank you!